# Return count and list of sentences where word appears using Java Streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm stuck trying to get in what sentences each word appears. The entry would be a list of sentences

```
Question, what kind of wine is best? 
White wine.
A question
```

and the output would be

```
// format would be: word:{count: sentence1, sentence2,...}
a:{1:3} 
wine:{2:1,2} 
best:{1:1} 
is:{1:1} 
kind:{1:1} 
of:{1:1} 
question:{2:1,3} 
what:{1:1}
white:{1:2}
```

This is what I get so far:

```
static void getFrequency(List<String> inputLines) {
  List<String> list = inputLines.stream()
     .map(w -> w.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+"))
     .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
     .map(String::toLowerCase)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());

   Map<String, Integer> wordCounter = list.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(w -> w, w -> 1, Integer::sum));
}
```

With that I'm only getting the count of times each word appears in all the sentences, but I need to get also the list of sentences where the word appears. It looks like maybe to get the id of sentences I can use `IntStream.range`, something like this:

```
 IntStream.range(1, inputLines.size())
          .mapToObj(i -> inputLines.get(i));
```

But I'm not sure if that is the best way to do it, I'm new with Java

Comment: What data type is `{count: sentence1, sentence2,...}` supposed to be?

Comment: It was just to show the result I want to print in the console, but the result could be,eg, `Map<String, List<Integer>>` where in the list would be the sentenceids

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a grouping collector to compute a word to index list map. Here's an example:

```
private static Map<String, List<Integer>> getFrequency(List<String> inputLines) {
    return IntStream.range(0, inputLines.size())
            .mapToObj(line -> Arrays.stream(inputLines.get(line)
                 .split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+"))
                 .map(word -> new SimpleEntry<>(word.toLowerCase(), line + 1)))
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, 
                  Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
}
```

With your test data, I get

```
{a=[3], what=[1], white=[2], question=[1, 3], kind=[1], 
 of=[1], best=[1], is=[1], wine=[1, 2]}
```

The count is easy to infer from the list size, so there should be no need for an additional class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and great answer @ernest_k

Comment: thought around duplicate words in a line since its not clear from the question, the resulting list in value would need to have duplicate line numbers to infer correct count @octavioccl

Comment: Good point @Naman. If a sentence can contain the same word twice and something like `question=[1, 3, 3]` (due to a sentence like `"A question question"`) is undesirable, then perhaps the result should be made a `Map<String, List<Integer>>`, with the last downstream collector changed accordingly (`Collectors.toSet()` instead of `Collectors.toList()`). There are unwieldy ways to do the same to get a list of distinct values, but it's up to the OP if it's even required.

Comment: If `question=[1, 3, 3]` is undesirable, then `Collectors.toSet()` is not really a great way to deal with the actual problem, since the count would be incorrectly inferred. For a similar reason, I initially thought the return type to be something like `Map<String, Map<Long, List<Integer>>>`, but the more I think of it, the more it looks to me like an unwanted complexity. So your answer as it is remains simpler with valid assumptions.

Comment: Come to think of it, toSet would lose the count, which the OP needs. @Naman.
**Octaviocci** please advise if you'd rather avoid a repeated word in a sentence showing up multiple times as the same sentence index. Maybe that's not a problem.

Comment: This is quite elegant. Wouldn't `Map.entry()` be a better choice than `new SimpleEntry<>()` as it does not require `AbstractMap`?

Comment: @GeneMcCulley requires Java9+, but yeah reads better if possible to use.

Comment: @GeneMcCulley thanks. `Map.entry()` would surely be better, but it's only available on Java 9+

Comment: @ernest_k, I was checking the problem and they don't specify if the sentenceid should be repeated for each time it appears in a sentence, it looks like its just to know where it appears, for now I think is ok as you have your answer